How many axis' of rotation are there in a general N-dim space?
I'm learning 3D graphics and I stumbled upon a weird fact.
In 2D, there's only one axis of rotation (perpendicular to the xy plane)
In 3D there's suddenly 3 axis' of rotation? (perpendicular to x plane, y plane and z plane)
I would expect either N-dim space to have N axis' of rotation OR N-dim space have N-1 axis' of rotation, not both at the same time!
So what is the rule? And how many axis of rotation would exist in e.g. 4D space? Are my assumptions even correct, or perhaps 3D space only has 2 axis of rotation and we introduce the 3rd one for convenience?
I tried looking up 4D rotations but got immediately overwhelmed unfortunately. The answer at Axes of rotation in 4D seems to suggest that 4D has 0 rotation axis' which is not helping my understanding to be honest

There are infinitely many axes of rotation in 3D space, but you only actually use one of them at a time. Things get much weirder in higher dimensions.

In 3D there are infinitely many axes of rotation.

Oh no, yeah that complicates things. How about if I ask about "the minimal number of axis' required to achieve any rotation"?

Still just one axis in 3D, but it can be aligned in any direction. Note that the answer to your linked question points out that there is actually no axis of rotation for a 2D rotation either. You appear to be visualizing an "axis" for a 2D rotation by embedding the 2D space in a 3D space where that axis lives, but in the 2D space itself, all you have is that one fixed point.

That's true, I did project the 2D space into 3D, but perhaps that's not the smartest. I'm just trying to figure out how do rotations behave in general and the fact that 2D and 3D rotations behave so differently, and 4D I don't even understand, is wrecking me hah

Perhaps a "rotation axis" does not mean what you seem to think it means. If you want to think in a consistent, intrinsic manner: in 2D one rotates around a 0D point; in 3D one rotates around a 1D line; in 4D one rotates around a 2D plane; in 5D one rotates around a 3D space; and in general, in $n$ dimensions, one rotates around an $n-2$ dimensional subspace.

That's so smart!! So N-dim rotation is around a N-2 dim subspace and the axis of rotation is what defines the subspace around which we are rotating, amazing!

Now I have more questions which will keep me up at night haha. The fact that we rotate around N-2 hyperspaces suggest the existence of arbitrary N-m hyperspace transformations, perhaps N-1 transformation could be a simple mirror, but I have no idea what would N-3 transformations be

Note that on a sphere in 3d there are infinitely many rotations which can move one point to another. For example the axis can be orthogonal to the great circle which contains both points or the axis can be through the center and the midpoint between the two on that same great circle. See if you can find some others to help build intuition.
